# Filtering Dictionary with Nested Lists Embedded

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, filter, nested-lists

I am looking to filter the following by the 'abv' value (using only the lower end of the range. ex. if 'ABV: 4.5-5.5%' I will use 4.5 for the value of the ABV) and the 'cuisine'. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import csv
from html.parser import HTMLParser


r = requests.get("https://www.webstaurantstore.com/article/27/different-types-of- 
beers.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
beer_titles = soup.find_all('h3')[3:-1]
beer_titles_list = []
for b in beer_titles:
    result = b.text.strip()
    beer_titles_list.append(result)

helpme = soup.find_all('p')
def __init__(self):
    helpme().__init__()
    helpme.reset()
    helpme.fed = []
helpme_clean = []
for d in helpme:
    result = d.text.strip()
    helpme_clean.append(result)
attributes = helpme_clean[36:-20]


helpme_clean = []
for d in helpme:
    result = d.text.strip()
    helpme_clean.append(result)
attributes = helpme_clean[36:-20]
attributes
attributes = attributes[:252]
del attributes[231]
del attributes[205]
del attributes[204]
del attributes[203]
del attributes[200]
del attributes[191]
del attributes[170]
del attributes[169]
del attributes[168]
del attributes[144]
del attributes[126]
del attributes[125]
del attributes[124]
del attributes[118]
del attributes[107]
del attributes[81]
del attributes[80]
del attributes[79]
del attributes[68]
del attributes[67]
del attributes[66]
del attributes[45]
del attributes[44]
del attributes[43]
del attributes[22]
del attributes[21]
del attributes[20]

n = 5
main_list = [attributes[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(attributes), n)]
main_dict = dict(zip(beer_titles_list, main_list))
main_dict
```

The goal is to take user input (ABV% preference and cuisine to pair with) and find recommendations on styles of beer to choose from. I am trying to set up a filter system to be able to return only the beers that match both the ABV% preference and cuisine pairing. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct idea to match the `'4.5'` of `'ABV: 4.5-5.5%'` is to use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Here's the code:

```
import re
string='ABV: 4.5-5.5%'
output=re.search(r'([\d\.]+)\-[\d\.]+',string)[1]
```

As for to remove multiply values in a list, using the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a simple method:

```
new_list=[old_list[i] for i in range(len(old_list)) if not i in indices]
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np 
old_list=np.random.random(10)
indices=np.random.choice(np.arange(0,10),5)
new_list=[old_list[i] for i in range(len(old_list)) if not i in indices]

print('The original list is:',list(old_list))
print('The indices to be removed are:',list(indices))
print('The new list is:',list(new_list))
```

Output:

> The original list is:  [0.9233779986812494, 0.47976112127600334,
>   0.2669764806705126, 0.8598525413490794, 0.03257522197544993, 0.472960144751734, 0.07720026239677213, 0.22969097769323488, 0.3039956214047107, 0.5079366193702746]
>
> The indices to be removed are:  [2, 0, 1, 7, 3]
>
> The new list is: [0.03257522197544993, 0.472960144751734,
>   0.07720026239677213, 0.3039956214047107, 0.5079366193702746]